# Building C++ API of Third Party Library in Visual Studio C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, build

I have been successfully testing an image processing library (https://github.com/libvips/libvips) in a C++ project in VS2017. I am new to C/C++ and I have been following the [documentation here](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/using-from-c.html) which describes the C way of using the library. There are features I would like to try in the C++ API, but the C++ API needs to be built with the same compiler as my project. According to the author:

> It's slightly awkward to set up under Windows. The problem is that C++
> does not have a ABI, so you must use exactly the same C++ compiler for
> your whole project. This means the libvips C++ win binary (built with
> g++) won't work with MSVC C++.
>
> You need to copy the libvips C++ API source code into your own project
> and build it with your own code. It's just a few files and pretty
> simple to incorporate:
>
> https://github.com/libvips/libvips/tree/master/cplusplus

I have made several attempts to build the minimal set of files but I have not had any success.

My steps so far:

- Create a C++ console app in VS2017, set to Debug and x64
- Extract the 'vips-dev-8.10' folder from vips-dev-w64-all-8.10.6.zip to where the project file is (this contains all the built .dll files, .lib files, .h files etc.)
- Extract 'cplusplus' folder from 'libvips-master.zip' to where the project file is (this has all the project source files including the cplusplus folder which is the part I have to build per the above explanation)
- Add the following folders to Project > Properties > C/C++->General > Additional Include Directories

C:\Projects\ConsoleApplicationVIPS3\ConsoleApplicationVIPS3\cplusplus\include\vips
C:\Projects\ConsoleApplicationVIPS3\ConsoleApplicationVIPS3\vips-dev-8.10\include
C:\Projects\ConsoleApplicationVIPS\ConsoleApplicationVIPS\vips-dev-8.10\lib\glib-2.0\include
C:\Projects\ConsoleApplicationVIPS\ConsoleApplicationVIPS\vips-dev-8.10\include\glib-2.0

- Add the 5 .cpp files from the cplusplus folder into the project Source Files folder and Add them in the project tree.
  Build the project.
  As a result I get the following errors:

[image]

I haven't written any code yet. I thought I should just be able to point to the .h include files and compile the required C++ files.   It's not clear to me what else I might need to add, but it definitely seems like I don't understand the correct procedure to build the project. I watched some videos on C++ compilation like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4s55GgAg0I) but I cant see where I went wrong.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

***EDITS 3-Jun-21***

I have made some changes. I have instead extracted the exact version of the library according to the suggestion by @Frank, and I also discovered the usefulness of the compiler output window, thanks @Alan Birtles.

I am still getting errors, but I am not clear why. The first error is:

```
E0020   identifier "VImage" is undefined
```

Which is odd because I have added the folders to Project > Properties > C/C++->General > Additional Include Directories, and one of them is ..\cplusplus\include\vips which contains VImage8.h

[image]

And the Output window shows

[image]

Any further advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Kinda hard to tell from a distance, but generally speaking, you would want to use the same version (8.10.6) of the cpp API as the underlying library as opposed to master. It seems you used the "download zip" feature of github. In that case, on github, click the 'master' dropdown at the top left and switch it to the appropriate **tag** (not branch) before downloading (there)[https://i.imgur.com/OOIXY1z.png]. If this fixes your problem, I'll make a proper answer out of it.

Comment: Use Microsoft's packager tool like vcpkg to do the installation of third party libraries automatically to your visual studio project for you using just a one liner code.

Comment: @seccpur doesn't look like libvips is on vcpkg, so I'm not sure how that helps OP.

Comment: @Frank:  A quick google search shows libvips with vcpkg, although I haven't use it.

Comment: @seccpur all I find is github issues discussing how to make it happen. Can you provide a link please? I'm curious.

Comment: @Frank: You're right, not listed on vcpkg.

Comment: look in the compiler output window, the error list is only a summary and doesn't include a lot of the information. Solve the first error first as that may be causing other errors

Comment: I think you are still missing some includes. Can you try to find the function declaration of the first error you see ?